# Can I pass params as an array?

Tags: function, testing, rust

E.g., instead of

```
assert_eq!(add(2,3), 5);
```

is there some way to call something like

```
let params: [u32; 2] = [2 ,3];
assert_eq!(call!(&add, params), 5);
```

I would find this functionality very useful for testing. E.g., if I want to write multiple tests for a function that takes a large number of params, I want to be able to reuse a dummy param object like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    const dummy: [u32; 5] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; 

    #[test]
    fn test_first_param() {
        let mut params = dummy;
        params[0] = 1;
        assert_eq!(call!(&add, params)), 1);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_second_param() {
        let mut params = dummy;
        params[1] = 1;
        assert_eq!(call!(&add, params)), 1);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If this functionality does not exist, would anyone be interested in me making and publishing a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no feature in the language that enumerates over an array and passes each element as an argument. You're correct that you'd need a macro.